# Can a named list be returned from lapply function in R?

Tags: r, list, lapply

I have the following sample data in which I want to return a named list as an output of lapply function.

```
data(sample_matrix)
vect = c("a","b","c")
output <- lapply(vect, function(list_member){
  sample <- list(x = list_member, y = list_member)

  # I want to name the entire sample list, not the x and y elements while returning from lapply
  names(sample.xts) <- list_member

  return(sample)
  })
str(output)
```

The output looks like following -

```
List of 3
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ a : chr "a"
  ..$ NA: chr "a"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ b : chr "b"
  ..$ NA: chr "b"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ c : chr "c"
  ..$ NA: chr "c"
```

However, it should look like this

```
List of 3
 $ a :List of 2
  ..$ x: chr "a"
  ..$ y: chr "a"
 $ b :List of 2
  ..$ x: chr "b"
  ..$ y: chr "b"
 $ c :List of 2
  ..$ x: chr "c"
  ..$ y: chr "c"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `setNames`

```
output <- setNames(output, unique(unlist(output)))
str(output)
#List of 3
# $ a:List of 2
#  ..$ x: chr "a"
#  ..$ y: chr "a"
# $ b:List of 2
#  ..$ x: chr "b"
#  ..$ y: chr "b"
# $ c:List of 2
#  ..$ x: chr "c"
#  ..$ y: chr "c"
```

---

If we start from the beginning, it can be named `vector`

```
output <- lapply(setNames(vect, vect), function(list_member){
      list(x = list_member, y = list_member)
    })
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks @akrun!

Comment: A shorthand for `setNames(vect, vect)` in your second option is `rlang::set_names(vect)`

Comment: @camille Yes, with external libraries. Not sure if the OP wanted to load more packages